# How to get route url in controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, helper

I can get the URL for a route in my view with an HTML helper, but how can I do the same thing from within controllers?

Comment: how are you getting it in the view?

Comment: It would be helpful if we had the example from the view to reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the exact same code.
`Controller` also has the `Url` helper property.